# Dates from excel worksheet to userform in dd/mm/yyy format?

Tags: excel, date, vba

So, this is really driving me crazy now, I have had a lot of problems working with dates on VBA due to formatting issues, since I need my dates to be in dd/mm/yyyy format. I did a lot of searching on the internet, and I found a lot of discussion about these date formats in VBA, however I could not find a solution to my problem.

**The problem**: I have some dates stored on a worksheet, formatted as dd/mm/yyyy - I stored them there through userforms, and I had some problems with the formatting but it worked out fine in the end -, and I want to display one of those dates on a userform label. Here is the code I wrote for that:

```
 Me.Label2_Prazo.Caption = Format(Plan1.Cells(pos, 5), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

However, it still displays the date incorrectly. On my worksheet, the date is stored as "05/03/2016" (As in march 5th, 2016), but still whenever I try to display it on the userform it appears as "03/05/2016".

I have already tried many different ways to make this work, but I can't seem to solve this.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: try this `Format(Plan1.Cells(pos, 5).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")`

Comment: Dates are not stored in worksheets as "dmy" or "mdy" or "ymd".  They are stored as the number of days since 1900.  For 5Mar2016 that number is 42434.  Excel displays 42434 as a date because the number format tells it to.  What does `Plan1.Cells(pos, 5).Value` contain.

Comment: I actually also still had a problem with my writing from the userform to the worksheet, so of my some dates were actually being written to the worksheet on the wrong format. That made me think the problem as on the conversion from sheet to userform, when actually the format was already wrong on the worksheet. Thank you all for your help! (And for suggesting that I confirmed what was written on that cell)

Comment: `? Format(42434,"dd/mm/yyyy")` in the Immediate Window produces `05/03/2016`.  To me it appears `Plan1.Cells(pos, 5).Value` does not contain 42434.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (personally) favor the solution of constructing the format myself. This is probably due to the fact that I have worked for several year in a corporate environment where I had to deal with Russian, Hungarian, German, USA, Chinese, and many other date formats. Some of them follow strange formats such as `YYYY. MMMM D.`. Anyway, in your case I would therefore propose the following:

```
Dim dttDate As Date

dttDate = CDate(Plan1.Cells(pos, 5).Value)
Me.Label2_Prazo.Caption = Right("0" & Day(dttDate), 2) & "/" & Right("0" & Month(dttDate), 2) & "/" & Year(dttDate)
```

On another note: while in VBA I try to construct most of my dates using `DateSerial` ONLY to ensure that I am really generating the date I intend to (and don't get mixed up in the various different date formats).